# Best approach for implementing configurable permissions and roles in Django

Tags: django, django-permissions, django-role-permissions

I'm working on a Django application and I need to implement configurable permissions and roles. I want to be able to add new roles and associate multiple tasks with each role for specific modules in my Django app. What would be the best approach to achieve this?

I would like to have the flexibility to define different roles with specific permissions and assign them to users. Additionally, I want to be able to manage these roles and permissions easily, preferably through my application not django admin.

Any insights, recommendations, or examples of how to implement this functionality in Django would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest reading this three-part series. It will transform you into an expert on DRF permissions:

Part 1: Learn about DRF permissions at: https://testdriven.io/blog/drf-permissions

Part 2: Explore built-in permission classes for DRF at: https://testdriven.io/blog/built-in-permission-classes-drf

Part 3: Dive into custom permission classes for DRF at: https://testdriven.io/blog/custom-permission-classes-drf